# Guest posting vs commenting for building backlinks

Tags: seo, backlinks

In case of building backlinks, does the above two methods generates the same effect? I mean when I need to get a backlink from a quality site Its easy to leave a comment with some useful content and a link. But writing a guest post consumes much time and effort. If the requirement is to get a backlink does the above two methods generates an equal impact on SEO. Or if the link is within the main content does it generates a higher impact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blog Comment: A big NO these days.

Guest Post: Not the best approach anymore but there are some expectations.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en

Having said that both can be done to an extent in highly relevant manner, but i would say it may not give you any significant ranking boost. For low competition industry, it might be just OK.

Comment: So then what are the techniques for a significiant ranking boost?

Comment: There are so may techniques. Build quality content on your website which will be useful for the user, market those content in social media and other places bring more traffic and possibly people will link you. You can link your post from rich sites, G+, FB, LinkedIn etc. Meaning shortcuts will not take you far in SEO.